# Memory matching Game

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am developing a memory  game in android where in user has to match the correct card.I have images.Should I use grid views to show the images?Once user clicks on two correct images ,the  correct images has to disappear.How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `GridView` is a good approach.  Have the adapter for the grid return the back of the card image for all cards initially and keep track of whether a card needs to be shown.  Use `OnItemClickListener` to determine when a card is selected.  There, tell your adapter that a card needs to be rotated and tell the grid view that the data has changed - to redraw the card.  Then in the adapter keep a flag against each item to indicate whether it needs to show the back of the card or the actual card - and in your `getView` method draw the corresponding image.

Write some code, try debuggin it.  When you're stuck, come back and post some specific code with your specific questions.

Comment: can u please give some examples?

Comment: @SujayKaranj.  Not yet.  You need to show some effort on your part before we can help.  SO is not a code-generation site.